# pre-commit hook to block the commit other than svnsync

Tags: svn, svnsync

I need to maintain a mirrored repository for users(read-only). I need to block all commits except the commit from svnsync. I think I can use a pre-commit hook to block commits other than the svnsync?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use a hook? Can't you just use the `authz` file to set appropriate permissions?

E.g.

```
[/]
svnsync = rw
* = r
```

Comment: is `svnsync` in this case the username? Also, is `authz` respected in anything other than DAV-based scenarios?

Comment: Yes, it's the username. Not sure about authz for non-DAV sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the mirror - and concentrate on getting your access control straight in the master so the users can be constrained to read only access.

You'll set that up in much the same way as the scenario you described.  only allowing the service account that does the svnsync to commit.  There are lots of options here, depending on your setup. Are you integrating with LDAP?  How are you currently doing authentication/authorization?

check out [svnperms](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/svnperms.py)